# Cannot chmod for a folder from other hard disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, hard-drive

I have a SSD and a HDD in my laptop. Ubuntu is in SSD. The HDD is divided to 2 partition. 500GB for window and 500GB for both with `FAT` format (called **`DATA`**). I must work with `sudo` each time I work on the **`DATA`**.

I have a folder in `DATA` is `image`. I try to chmod: `sudo chmod 777 -R image` but It does not work although no error logged.

Comment: FAT filesystem does not have filesystem permissions. They are simulated with mount options on Linux to make it feel like Posix filesystem. See `man 8 mount` for vfat mount options.

Comment: Try mounting the partition with `sudo mount -t vfat -o umask=000 /dev/sdXY /mnt/fat` but adjust to suit your partition and chosen mount point. Once you are happy add the equivalent entry to fstab